# Postgresql is not getting connected

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

When I am trying to connect to postgresql, getting an error like :

> psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
>         Is the server running locally and accepting
>         connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

How can I fix it?

Comment: Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpostgresql%5D++Is+the+server+running+locally+and+accepting+connections+on+Unix+domain+socket)

Comment: basically, PostgreSQL service is down and reasons can be multiple. have a look at log files.